# How to handle delay response from axios to react query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

For testing purpose, I am calling axios with setTimeout like below, this will call and get response after 5 second

```
async function UserLogin(user) {
  console.log("USER LOGIN API CALLED");
  console.log(user);
  setTimeout(async() => {
    return await axios.post("/Auth/Login", user);
  },5000)
}
```

Here is my useMutation

```
export const apiAuthLogin = () => {
  //const loginNavigate = useNavigate();
  return useMutation({
    mutationKey: ["login"],
    mutationFn: async(user) => await UserLogin(user),

    onSuccess: async (res) => {
      console.log("useMutation Login Succcess");

      console.log(await res?.data);  //undefined error, because still axios is in timeout

      localStorage.setItem("Token", res?.data);
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      console.log('useMutation Login Failed')
      console.log(err)
    }
  });
};
```

But onSuccess called immediately without waiting for axios return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because all Code in UserLogin is synchronous and executed immediately (setTimeout will cause the inner function to be queued for execution at a later stage, but the execution of setTimeout itself still is synchronous).

To have the outcome you desire you would have to wrap setTimeout in an awaited promise which resolves once the callback is fired.

Edit: Here is an example of the updates UserLogin fn.

```
async function UserLogin(user) {
  console.log("USER LOGIN API CALLED");
  console.log(user);
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await axios.post("/Auth/Login", user);
      resolve()
  },5000)
  })
}
```

We wrap the timeout in a Promise which we resolve once the timeout comes back from the queue and our post logic ended. This will make sure that the execution of UserLogin is suspended until the timeout callback fired.

Comment: thanks for your reply, you mean to wrap a `mutateFn` itself?. I tried to setTimeout for `mutateFn` too. still same result. could you add sample code with your answer please?.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example